# How to get the yahoo news data of a person and orgnaization using RSS news api

Tags: java, rss, yahoo-api

I am working on yahoo news data. I have succeed of getting the news of particular keyword by using rss news api. But I also want news data about a person and organization i.e., Suppose I want yahoo news about Obama,Clinton,Narendramodi etc like that and Organizations like apple,microsoft,dell etc what is the way to get that data ?

Here is the api which I am using

```
YAHOO_RSS_API : http://news.yahoo.com/rss/world
```

[World News Headlines - Yahoo News[^]](http://news.yahoo.com/rss/world)

How to get person and organization news ? can anyone suggest me how to acheive those news

**What I have tried:**

According to my research there is an option of getting persons and any organization data by using search api. I have tried using yahoo search api but it was banned.

```
SEARCH_API : http://api.search.yahoo.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=30355988901717343&query=apple
```

Comment: The yahoo search api  has been discontinued. You'll need to find something different.

Comment: Yes search api was discontinued i knew. What's that different path ? @zapl

Comment: A different API. Probably not Yahoo at all. Idk, http://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/sdk?category=20055 has maybe something for you.

Comment: Is it not possible to get the yahoo news data by giving any keyword in the api itself and that keyword can be person name,organization name or any word @zapl

Comment: Yahoo has as far as I can see exactly 0 APIs to get news/people/organization.  A few rss feeds like http://news.yahoo.com/rss/obama do exist but this works only for a select few. https://developer.yahoo.com/rss// still lists http://news.search.yahoo.com/news/rss?p=motorcycle&c=&eo=UTF-8 but that has also been shut down. They (like most other search services) don't want that anybody can get results pogrammatically without generating traffic that also sees their ads. The things that yahoo still offers are: https://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html

Comment: yes thank you zapl for your information. I am also getting only one person data i.e., OBAMA and one organization data i.e., APPLE through rss api. I am not getting any other persons and organizations data except those two. But it's strange that why are we getting only those two keywords data and not others info. Do you have any idea regarding this wierd case ?

Comment: It's not an open API and it's not meant to provide feeds on demand. They will have a list of keywords that result in a RSS feed and anything not on that (small) list will not. RSS is no longer very popular and I would expect that the remaining feeds will also vanish (in the next years).